# How to perform action only when tabbar access view controller swift 3?

Tags: swift3, uitabbarcontroller

So, I have a view controller in which I have a `UISegmentedControl` connected to do a choice.

However, I want to set that `UISegementedControl` to unselected only if that view controller is accessed by pressing the tab bar to go to it. If it is accessed any other way, it can perform the standard `viewWillAppear` function that I have set, but only if it is accessed through the tab bar controller, I want the selection to be empty.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Define a class variable in your controller, for e.g. `isShownFromTabBar` with `true` as the default value.

If you are showing the controller from a segue or from a code, set this variable to `false`.

Comment: It is a tab bar controller so the view controller is shown by a relationship segue therefore I don't know how to add any code to the segue.

Comment: That's the catch here; you don't need to implement code when the relationship establishes. You need to change the variable when you are *not* displaying the view controller from the tab bar controller.

Comment: Sure I understand that, but how exactly do I define the "not displaying the view controller from the tab bar controller". How will the code know whether or not the view controller is being accessed by the tab bar controller or some other method?